Movie that starts with a guy killing a buffalo
More than 5 years ago, I watched a non-english movie online. It was in the erotic (not porn) section. Also it was probably from the 90s or earlier! I only watched half of it. It started with a guy killing a buffalo in a deserted area. And there were I think 2 kids who cry hysterically seeing this. 
Other than this there's very little I remember from the movie. The guy who kills the buffalo has some erotic scenes at home. The movie has lots of family affairs. 
After all these years, it still bothers me that I didn't finish watching it!
EDIT: adding these info

It was a buffalo and not a bison for sure.
The people in the movie were of the african bushman type (or may be from the amazon?). 
They lived in traditional homes like huts. They main guy is able to watch a girl take bath inside because there are many see-throughs in the hut. 
The main guy has a wife (I think). But he has sex with another girl who lives around the house (probably his sister in law)
I can't be sure at all about the language (sorry!). 
There are 2 boys in the movie (<10 YO). 
The movie revolved around the family and the people around the house talking to each other (this main guy trying to score). 

These are all that I remember. 

Seems difficult to answer, because we don't have much information to start searching. A clue in the direction of language/country of origin could be helpful. What did the characters look like ? I mean asian / caucasian / south american ? You can also tell us about the landscape shown in movie, it will help identify the place.

By "buffalo", do you mean buffalo? Or bison?

Please see my edit. Added some info.

I don't think they were Bushmen. It seems this is a film called Silip (AKA Daughters of Eve) from 1985, a crime drama with exploitative overtones from the Philippines.

In the remote countryside of Ilongo, various women are sexually abused by local men. Two sisters meet Simon, the most attractive man in the village, and fight over him--one constantly haunted by Catholic dogma because of the abuse she suffered previously.

They do live in huts in that village. And in the beginning:

[The film] opens quite viciously with the brutally bludgeoning and slaughter of a buffalo, by village butcher Simon, in full view of the neighborhood children. The children scream and cry for the animal to be spared...

Struggling to find clips or images that are SFW... Let's just say they exist online. :/

This is it...!!! can't believe how happy this make me. I don't really care anymore if I watch the movie or not, so glad to put this behind me. I have no idea why not remembering the name of the movie bothered me for such a long time. Thank you!!!
